# Angular 4: How can I get the Parent Component's value to be updated by a changed value in a child Component without the Parent doing any extra work

Tags: angular, components, angular-directive

I want to be able to accomplish an automatic update (2-way binding0 of a property that is in a parent controller from a child controller without the parent knowing that a @Output event needs to be passed into the child controller like I have in:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZWDuhhiKIQxrxFmfP9Wa)

**App**

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="app">
      Parent: {{ myValue }}
      <myinput 
         [(zModel)]='myValue'
         (zChange)='valueChanged($event)'
      ></myinput> 
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
  myValue: string = 'Hello World';
  valueChanged(event) {
    //alert('app: onchange (' + event + ")");
    this.myValue = event;
  }
}
```

**MyinputComponent**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'myinput',
    template: `
      <hr>
   <div >
        Inside Component: <u>{{ zModel }}</u> <br/><br/>
        <input type="text" 
            [(ngModel)]="zModel"
            (input)="valueChanged($event)"
            >
   </div>
  `
})
export class MyinputComponent {
    @Input() 
    zModel: string = '';

    @Output()
    zChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  valueChanged(item){
    //alert('onchange (' + this.zModel + ')');
        this.zChange.emit(this.zModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, how did it go with the answer I provided, did it meet your requirements? :)

Comment: Awesome!   That was a bit too easy, once you pointed out the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by *not doing any extra work*, you mean that you want to remove the method `valueChanged` from the parent. If so, you are on the right track by marking the two-way binding:

```html
[(zModel)]='myValue'
```

the only thing you need to change in the child to achieve this two-way-binding is to actually add the suffix `Change` to the exact name of your variable. So instead of

```ts
@Output()
zChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

it should be

```ts
@Output()
zModelChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

as your `@Input` is marked as `zModel`.

This also of course means that in the child `valueChanged` you need to mark the correct variable name:

```ts
valueChanged(item){
  this.zModelChange.emit(this.zModel);
}
```

So after these changes you can remove `valueChanged` from parent, and the child tag would just look like this:

```ts
<myinput [(zModel)]='myValue'></myinput>
```

Here's your updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/eYx5wXnYauzqKXtduOvX?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @AJT_82, Saved a lot of headaches

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!! Since it solved your issue, consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer, which marks the question as solved :)